# CloudKit internal error (1/5000), "Public sharing identity on share is different."

Tags: ios, cloudkit

This occurs when attempting to send a CKShare invitation through the UICloudSharingController. The `failedToSaveShareWithError` delegate method returns this error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIShareErrorDomain error 0.),
[AnyHashable("NSUnderlyingError"): <CKError 0x10c6ed230: "Partial Failure" 
(2/1011); "Failed to modify some records"; partial errors: {
MyRecord:(MyRecord:__defaultOwner__) = <CKError 0x10c6e5340: 
"Internal Error" (1/5000); "Public sharing identity on share <CKRecordID: 
0x101a19bb0; recordName=MyRecord, 
zoneID=MyRecord:__defaultOwner__> is different. Expected <30250201 
01042051 9265a819 ae97af10 8ff8c2f4 c4621baf 50a893ea 1f174540 df6bb519 
d7fdb6>, got <30250201 010420b6 0286d3e0 b03a1427 4e51ade1 63775c13 81fb2751 
b88abb4f eb94abb5 6b98e3>">
}>]
```

Seems like the key message is, "Public sharing identity on share is different."
It has worked for me in the past, but now I always see this error. Any idea what is causing it or how to fix it?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this? I am running into this issue now. Changing the zone name clears the issue, but that's no use for a production system.

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/275485#275485

Comment: If I recall, it was a temporary issue that Apple must have fixed. You may want to use a technical support request if it persists.

Comment: Can't be that temporary.. I'm hitting it, non-reproducibly and infrequently. I'm wondering if it's related to creating the CKShare ahead of time and always using initWithShare: on UICloudSharingController. I have an Apple TSI open.